# C# Regex.Split - Would like to split a string by a char but allow the char to be used between ' and '

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to split a string by `/` but also allow anything between `'` and `'` to contain my split character. While removing the `'` and `'` from the split and any blanks.

example `/'TEST/:1'/3` is split into

- `Test/:1`
- `3`

I have something close:

```
regex.split(test, "/(?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)"
```

but it still has the `'` and blanks in it.

```
string[] fields = Regex.Split(Path, "/(?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)");
```

Sorry I well be more clear its my own pathing format for parsing EDI like file it works like this. `/Location:LineNumber/YPosition`. All I want to do so is get in a command line `/TEST:4/6 = /Location(Test):LineNumber(4)/YPosition(6)`. but my problem is that the Location is worked out by my code and could be anything up to the first delimiter. It could be a date format `12/03/03` which is common in EDI type files.

I would like to be able to get my command looking like this `/'12/03/03':4/6` so that when the Location is split by my regex.split it does not include anything between the (' and ') location.

Any help please?

Comment: Is it `'` or `"`? Your question mixes both.

Comment: I'm not fussed by which it is. Makes no difference

Comment: Its not a CSV standard, I'm trying to come up with my own Xpath like command for parsing a EDI(HL7) type file.

Answer (score 1):

It is not entirely clear what you're really trying to achieve. If you want to parse a CSV-like file format, better use a CSV parser; if you want to manipulate file paths, then use your standard library's path manipulation functions. Both are better equipped to deal with edge cases than a simple regex.

That said, you could do

```
MatchCollection allMatchResults = null;
Regex regexObj = new Regex(
    @" "" [^""]* ""  # either match a (double-)quoted string
    |                # or
    [^/\s]*          # a sequence of characters other than / or whitespace", 
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
allMatchResults = regexObj.Matches(subjectString);
```

This will not handle escaped quotes within quoted strings, but if those aren't present in your input, it should work.

Note that `"Test / 1"/1/2 3/45` will be split into `"Test / 1"`, `1`, `2`, `3` and `45` because blanks are removed and thereby also serve as separators.

Comment: Do you have a pointer to a convenient CSV parser that will support his file format?

Comment: @Gabe: For Python, yes (the built-in csv module supports custom delimiters), but I don't know C# well enough to suggest one.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "\"\"/one/\"two/threefour\"/five//";

            var separator = "/";

            var empty = "(?<empty>\\s*)";

            var word = string.Format("(?<word>[^{0}]+)",  separator);
            var quotedWord = "(?<word>[^\\\"]+)";

            var token = string.Format("((\"({0}|{1})\")|({0}|{2}))",empty, quotedWord, word);

            var pattern = string.Format("({0}/)+({0})", token);

            foreach (var capture in Regex.Match(input, pattern).Groups["word"].Captures)
                Console.WriteLine(capture);

        }


    }
```

Comment: `var comment = string.Format("{2}{1}{0}{3}{4}{3}","F","T","W","?","!");`

Answer (score 1):

`Split` is not really the right tool for this kind of job.  If you were only splitting on slashes it would be fine, but with the addition of optional quotes, it becomes much easier to match the fields rather than the delimiters.  Here's a regex that allows for single- or double-quoted strings and treats `/`, `:`, and whitespace as delimiters:

```
  Regex r1 = new Regex(@"
      ""(?<FIELD>[^""]*)""
      |
      '(?<FIELD>[^']*)'
      |
      (?<FIELD>[^""'/:\s]+)
  ", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

  string[] source = { @"/TEST:4/6", @"/'12/03/03':4/6" };
  foreach (string s in source)
  {
    foreach (Match m in r1.Matches(s))
    {
      Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["FIELD"].Value);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
  }
```

output:

```
TEST
4
6

12/03/03
4
6
```

Reusing the `FIELD` group name makes it easy to scrape off the quotes if the field has them.  Here's a more "semantic" approach that matches the whole string in one pass and uses named groups to pigeonhole the field values.  I just plug them into the replacement string, but you can access them with the `Groups` method as I did in the first example.

```
  Regex r2 = new Regex(@"
      / \s*
        (?:
           (?<Q>[""'])(?<LOC>(?:(?!\<Q>).)*)\1
         |
           (?<LOC>[^""'/:]+)
        ) \s*
      : \s* (?<LINE>\d+) \s*
      / \s* (?<YPOS>\d+)
    ", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

  foreach (string s in source)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(r2.Replace(s,
        @"Location(${LOC}):LineNumber(${LINE})/YPosition(${YPOS})")
    );
    Console.WriteLine();
  }
```

output:

```
Location(TEST):LineNumber(4)/YPosition(6)

Location(12/03/03):LineNumber(4)/YPosition(6)
```

This regex doesn't treat whitespace as a delimiter, but it allows for whitespace padding around the field values.  It also matches single- and double-quoted fields with the same construct.  That's not really worth the extra complexity in this case, but it's a technique that's worth knowing about.

Comment: How does your solution handle consecutive delimiters? e.g. in a CSV file, `foo,,bar,` has 4 values.

Comment: @Gabe: We're not talking about CSV, and nothing was said about consecutive delimiters in the question.

Comment: Alan: The question was about `Split` which treats consecutive delimiters the way a CSV file would (hence my example). Your solution has different semantics that you should either change or call out.

Comment: @Gabe: Sorry, I had to run off earlier.  The way I see it, we're still trying to help the OP find the right question to ask.  He *could* have said his problem was similar to CSV, and enumerated the differences.  He didn't do that, which indicates to me that CSV is not a useful starting point.  I could be wrong, of course, but it's okay; the CSV route is being explored, too.  What I'm trying to do is work from what the OP *has* told us, and deal with the complications as they arise.

Comment: Let's just assume that the OP has never heard of CSV and just wants to get a list of records between delimiters. He may never get an input string with `//` or it may just never occur to him that it will happen. With his idea of using `Regex.Split` he will get an empty string with `//` whether he realizes it or not. While it's fine to give an alternative solution, you should point out how it differs from his current solution.